How i can find missing values in column and convert them into null in spreadsheet
Missing values were incorrectly entered as zeroes, and i need to change them to null values before look for trends. The code i am using to do this is returning an error message. How to solve this
How to construct conditional formula to convert zeros into null.

Spreadsheet? Do you really want a SQL language answer? Which dbms are you using?

if you are searching in column then click on the column and write below formula then hit enter:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A=“0”, "NULL", A:A))


Note that you're using both curly and straight quotes above. As Intended?
